# Can we identify a tree from its roots? Would help a bunch with my sewer problem

Tags: identification, roots

[image]

I bought a home and keep having sewer backup problems. I do not have a tree in my yard however the town keeps saying it is on my side. This is costing me piles of money and if I could prove that these roots are from their tree.. omg that would be excellent!
Can you identify a tree by its roots??

Comment: It is unlikely, but post a picture of the roots and picture of the trees closest to the issue

Comment: Flush some herbicide and see what dies?

Comment: Evidently there is a product (or class of product?) made that purports to be a "foaming root killer" and purports to kill roots and prevent them from growing back. Sounds too good to be true, so it probably is, but might be worth a try?

Comment: What's the distance between the closest tree to your house and the sewer line? approximately how wide is the crown of that tree? What kind of tree is it?

Comment: @Kevinskio I'm not following, what was unclear about this question?  It seems like it already has a good answer from Bamboo, and I don't think the picture is necessary or even very helpful in this case.

Comment: @MackM This question was closed as it lacks details.  When the picture was added by Rox that represents new details.  It is up to the users here to determine whether to reopen or not.

Comment: @kevinskio I'm asking *how* this question 'lacked details' when it was closed.  What more details do we need for "Can we identify a tree from its roots?"? Bamboo provided a useful answer, and I feel I also understand what the asker is asking.  What other details would you look for in this question, to have not closed it?  I'm only sticking on this because I believe your vote counted 3x, and there are only [140](https://data.stackexchange.com/gardening/query/1786207/active-close-open-voters) voters who can reopen this question, so closing it feels heavy handed and unwelcoming to me.

Comment: @RohitGupta I would also be interested to hear your thoughts.

Comment: @MackM A location, a picture of the likely tree that the town is saying is "on their side", soil type.  Almost anything would help providing an answer.  Feel free to vote to reopen this question.

Comment: @MackM, comments are not for discussions of this type. My view is succinctly in my 1st comment.  I am not voting otherwise until more info is presented.  Without that its opinion based. The purpose of closure is to stop speculative answers. It does not smack the OP or delete the question. Why is that hard to understand?

Answer (score 3):

You can't on our own, but there should be laboratories who do this work. I'm in the UK so don't know what you have available where you are, but we have labs that specialise in tree root ID, usually labs associated with construction services or botanical laboratories. Samples are collected and sent to them in the manner they require, and they will identify what roots they are - architects and insurance companies quite often use these services. Use your search engine and look for 'laboratories that identify tree roots' and see what comes up. I'm intrigued that'the town' says its your tree or roots - if they've had the roots tested, they should be able to say specifically what type of tree it is... If they haven't had the roots tested, then how do they know it's on your side, where's the evidence? If there's only one tree and its not on your side, then what are these roots supposed to be growing from? You could ask these questions, but its probably quicker and easier to find out where you can get the roots tested and pay the fee for that rather than continually having to pay for sewer repairs. It goes without saying that you need to know for certain what variety of tree, preferably its botanical name, is growing in next door's yard to be able to tell whether the roots are from that or something else, though.

Comment: I had never heard of this service, really cool!  I think the 'on your side' is just that the municipal sewer is not blocked, so the blockage is 'on your side' (non-municipal sewer pipes).  I do not know where in the world the OP is, but where I live I am responsible for damage 'on my side', even if it is damaged by my neighbor's plant.